# date filter on shared calendar does not return all results

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am running the following query:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars('sharedcalendarid')/events?$filter=start/dateTime ge '2018-10-14T06:00:00.000Z' and end/dateTime le '2018-10-21T05:59:59.999Z'&$orderby=Start/DateTime&$top=50&$count=true`

What I'm seeing is that this query returns only 24 results, even though there are at least double that number of events in the week when I look at my calendar (which only has events from this one shared calendar on it).

Is there a bug with filtering events from a shared calendar? I've compared an event that doesn't show up with one that does and can't find any differences (tentative vs not, recurring versus not, etc.).

Comment: Do you have try to set the $top to different value and see the response?

Comment: Have you checked out the [Calendar View](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendarview) that is specific to be used with a start and an enddate.

Comment: The answer was for us to use a calendarview which expands all recurring meetings for you before returning them.